# Can't upgrade to Redis Server 4.x

Tags: apt, redis

Why is my system telling me version 3.x is the latest when clearly there's a version 4 and even 5?

```
$ sudo apt-get install redis-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
redis-server is already the newest version (2:3.0.6-1ubuntu0.3).
```

running `apt policy redis-server` outputs:

```
redis-server:
  Installed: 2:3.0.6-1ubuntu0.3
  Candidate: 2:3.0.6-1ubuntu0.3
  Version table:
 *** 2:3.0.6-1ubuntu0.3 500
        500 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:3.0.6-1 500
        500 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

I also ran `sudo apt-get update` to no avail. MY system (Ubuntu 16.04) insist 3 i the latest version. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What does `apt policy redis-server` tell you?

Comment: updated the issue with the results of the command you've mentioned here.

Comment: Ubuntu repos don't have the latest versions of software. You can try to look for it somewhere else.

Comment: If you upgrade your system to 18.04, you'll get the v.5

Comment: So 2.3 is the latest version available on Ubuntu 16.04. On 18.04 the version available is 5.4. If you want to use that version, you can 1) upgrade to 18.04, 2) ask the developers to backport version 5 to 16.04 or 3) compile the package yourself, if that is at all possible.

Comment: Maybe some PPA exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ cd redis-5.0.5
$ make
```

And then run redis-server:

```
$ src/redis-server
```